# Xamarin Forms: Issue with file upload (Xamarin.Essentials)

Tags: xamarin.forms, filenotfoundexception, xamarin.essentials

I was using `Plugin.FilePicker` to pick files from the device. It was working fine on android version 11 and below. But on android version 12 and above, it is breaking with below exception:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: uri
> at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00088] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11928
> at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:894
> at Android.Content.ContentResolver.Query (Android.Net.Uri uri, System.String[] projection, System.String selection, System.String[] selectionArgs, System.String sortOrder) [0x000a0] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Android.Content.ContentResolver.cs:1456
> at Plugin.FilePicker.IOUtil.GetDataColumn (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, System.String selection, System.String[] selectionArgs) [0x00013] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\IOUtil.android.cs:151
> at Plugin.FilePicker.IOUtil.GetPath (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri) [0x00167] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\IOUtil.android.cs:108
> at Plugin.FilePicker.FilePickerActivity.OnActivityResult (System.Int32 requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data) [0x00039] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\FilePickerActivity.android.cs:151
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Plugin.FilePicker.FilePickerImplementation.PickFile (System.String[] allowedTypes) [0x00028] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\FilePickerImplementation.android.cs:60
> at CatholicBrain.ConnectAppModule.CreateActivityPage.PickFile (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs args) [0x00075] in :0
> --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
> java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
> at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:245)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1225)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1184)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1140)
> at crc64424a8adc5a1fbe28.FilePickerActivity.n_onActivityResult(Native Method)
> at crc64424a8adc5a1fbe28.FilePickerActivity.onActivityResult(FilePickerActivity.java:48)
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8840)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5694)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5740)
> at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:54)
> at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2458)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)

I checked for any updates for `Plugin.FilePicker` and found that the package is deprecated. So I installed the `Xamarin.Essentials` package and updated codes for picking files. It is working fine on android version 12 and above.

```
Xamarin.Essentials.FileResult file = null;
file = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    filename_label.IsVisible = true;
    filename_label.Text = file.FileName;
    upload_layout.IsVisible = true;
}
```

But when I try to upload the file using our REST API it fails with below exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: hail-mary.pdf
> File name: 'hail-mary.pdf' ---> Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: hail-mary.pdf
> at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00068] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11524
> at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:848
> at Android.Content.Res.AssetManager.Open (System.String fileName) [0x0001f] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Android.Content.Res.AssetManager.cs:265
> at Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.PlatformOpenAppPackageFileAsync (System.String filename) [0x0001d] in D:\a_work\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\FileSystem\FileSystem.android.cs:48
> --- End of managed Java.IO.FileNotFoundException stack trace ---
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: hail-mary.pdf
> at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
> at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:893)
> at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:870)
> at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.n_onClick(Native Method)
> at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.onClick(ButtonRenderer.java:107)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7512)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7489)
> at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:857)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29034)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
> at Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.PlatformOpenAppPackageFileAsync (System.String filename) [0x00036] in D:\a_work\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\FileSystem\FileSystem.android.cs:52
> at Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync (System.String filename) [0x00000] in D:\a_work\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\FileSystem\FileSystem.shared.cs:16
> at CatholicBrain.ConnectAppModule.CreateActivityPage.UploadFile (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00126] in <8fb254ba200e4d369cb3f96cc3e665ff>:0

Upload Code:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
Stream stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(file.FileName);
byte[] data;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    data = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Dispose();
}
content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "\"fileUpload\"", $"\"{file.FullPath}\"");
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(REST API Path), content);
```

`file.FullPath` is provided on the upload code but getting `FileNotFoundException.`

Comment: Use FileName instead of FullPath, or just leave out that optional parameter entirely

Comment: @Jason Tried both of your suggestion, but no changes

Comment: which **specific** line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Jason There is no line number showing; when I tap on the upload file button, I get this exception. Unfortunately, the debuggers are not hitting.

Comment: then step through each line of code in the debugger until you hit the exception

Comment: @Jason Got answer from the below thread, could you please add it as your answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1144327/xamarin-forms-issue-with-file-upload-xamarinessent.html?childToView=1145028#answer-1145028

Comment: Since Jason has not come back, and as a summary, I will post the answer here from the link Sreejith Sree shared so that it will help others who have similar problems. Thank you very much for your support of MAUI. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `FilePicker.PickAsync();` to get the file, you do not need to use `Stream stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(file.FullPath);` to read it to stream.

Just use `Stream stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();` directly, then you can get the stream.